# How to create a DOM from a User's input in PHP5?

Tags: php, dom, web-applications

How to create a DOM from a User's input in PHP5?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the DOM API that has been part of the core since 5. For an XML string $xml, you can build a DOM object with

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

Manipulate it with the rest of the DOM API, defined at http://uk.php.net/DOM

Answer (score 0):

And when you need to inject it back into some other DOM (like your HTML page) you can export it again using the $dom->saveXML() method. The problem however is that it also exports an xml header (it's even worse for the saveHTML version). To get rid of that use this:

```
$xml = $dom->saveXML();
$xml = substr( $xml, strlen( "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is HTML, use the loadHTML method. Be ware that the input has to be valid code, so you might want to pipe it through [html tidy](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) first.